# What is the the correct way in Overloading the << Operator in cpp

Tags: c++, class, oop, overloading

I tried overloading the << operator as shown directly into the public section of a class but it didn't work

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& output, const Box& B){
        output << B.l << " " << B.b << " " << B.h;
        return output;
}
```

I tried overloading the << operator as shown above directly into the public section of a class but it didnt work, after asking a senior programmer about this he wrote this outside the class & made it a friend function:

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& output, const Box& B){
        output << B.l << " " << B.b << " " << B.h;
        return output;
}
```

Comment: Yes, as you already checked, the second solution is correct.

Comment: "Didn't work" is not a description of a problem, although my guess would be that you forgot to mark the first method `static`.

Answer (score 2):

In this pseudo-example

```cpp
class Thing
{
  ...
  void work(int arg);
  ...
};
```

the member-function is a *kind of* function implicitly taking a `Thing` as first argument, like if `my_thing.work(12)` was `work(my_thing, 12)`.
It is absolutely not a valid substitution, but it is just to give the idea for the remaining of the explanation.

Back to your example, when you write `std::cout << my_box`, the compiler understands the usage of the operator `<<` as this function call `operator<<(std::cout, my_box)`.
If `operator<<` for `Box` was a member-function of `std::cout` this could work, but actually the standard streams don't know anything about your `Box` type.

If you provide `operator<<` as a member-function of `Box`, then it means that the left operand, which could be considered as a hidden first parameter as described in the pseudo-example above, should be a `Box`.
But when you write `std::cout << my_box`, the left operand is not a `Box` but `std::cout`.

In this case, the only solution is to provide a **non-member** function with the expected arguments in the correct order, hence the second solution you tried and found as working.